# How to create sitemap in Magento 2

Tags: sitemap, magento2

How can we create sitemap.xml in Magento 2, it is not being generated even I have done configuration setting in  Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> XML sitemap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If sitemap is not generated through CRONJOB, then can create it manually as well using below steps:

1. login to Magento 2 admin
2. Navigate to Maketing -> SEO & Search -> Site Map
3. Click on 'Add Sitemap'
4. Make required entries there
5. Click on 'Save & Generate'

That's it. Your sitemap.xml has been generated in given path

Comment: This generates the sitemap.xml. In `store -> setting -> configuration -> catalog -> XML sitemap` there are frequency settings that suggest this is run by a cronjob. Is this accurate? If we install the crontab, the sitemap will occasionally be updates?